# How to join specific columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

In pandas,  specific column join in Pyspark is perform by this code:

```
datamonthly=datamonthly.merge(df[['application_type','msisdn','periodloan']],how='left',on='msisdn')
```

I tried similar logic using Pyspark

```
datamonthly = datamonthly.join(datalabel
            , datamonthly['msisdn'] == datalabel['msisdn']
            , 'left' ).select(datamonthly['*'], datalabel.select('application_type','msisdn','periodloan'))
```

Here's the error message

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[application_type: string, msisdn: string, periodloan: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is in the select portion of the code,here you go:

```
datamonthly = datamonthly.alias('datamonthly').join(datalabel
        , datamonthly['msisdn'] == datalabel['msisdn']
        , 'left' ).select('datamonthly.*' , datalabel.application_type, datalabel.msisdn, datalabel.periodloan)
```

note that you can select by doing:

```
.select(df_name.column_name)
```

or:

```
.select(df_name['column_name'])
```